# Android list scroll animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

In my android application I am showing list for which I used recyclerview + cardview.For this I refered following link :-

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

I am able to show list as below :-[image: list using recyclerview + cardview]

But now I want show animation during scrolling only of list as shown in below link :-
https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/268236/screenshots/1659780/profile_interaction_by_ehsan_rahimi.gif

Kindly help me to achieve the same.
Kindly provide me suggestion.